# How do I make a DOORS DXL attribute based on the value of another attribute?

Tags: scripting, ibm-doors

X and Requirement are existing attributes.

I want to create an attribute Z such that, for the given object, 
if Requirement=True, then Z={the value of attribute X},
but if Requirement=False, then Z={Object Heading and Object Text}.

What is the DXL for making this attribute?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This is untested code but try something like this: (assuming attribute z exists as text)

Module m = current
Object o


for o in m do
{
   if ((o."Requirement") == "true")
   {
       o."z" = o."x" ""
   }
   else   // requirement = false
   {
       o."z" = o."Object Heading" "\n" o."Object Text" ""

   }
}
```